# Change text of bus destination sign at runtime

Tags: blender, unreal-4, blueprints

I have rigged a bus in blender and imported it into Unreal.

Now I want to change the text of the destination sign at run time.

How can i do this?

Comment: You could use dynamic material :-?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in C++ or Blueprints?

Comment: this is easy to do in blueprints, there is an action node called "set material" if I remember correctly, I haven't used Unreal for a while.